# IOS How to debug 9 seconds cpu time over 36 seconds (25% cpu average), exceeding limit of 15% cpu over 60 seconds

Tags: swift, swiftui, background, core-location

The high cpu usage rate threshold looks to have been lowered on iOS 15. Possibly from 80% in 60sec to 15% in 60sec? I have noticed that my app does NOT run correctly on IOS 15 and the background operations seem to stop like location, and some timers... I have a lot of @Published property's being updated while in the background, would this affect the background operations terminating after ~40 seconds in the background? If So how would I go about Updating my UI and keeping the constant updates to the published property.

I am getting the message:
Event:            cpu usage
Action taken:     none
CPU:              9 seconds cpu time over 36 seconds (25% cpu average), exceeding limit of 15% cpu over 60 seconds
CPU limit:        9s
Limit duration:   60s
CPU used:         9s
CPU duration:     36s
Duration:         35.85s
Duration Sampled: 25.92s
Steps:            5

Comment: Probably a good opportunity to get comfortable with Instruments and start benchmarking your code to see what is taking all of that time/energy.